# "Azure Web App Deploy" vs "Deploy Azure App Service"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If we are deploying a **basic** WebApp / WebApi, both these tasks from Microsoft appear to do the same thing - deploy to an appservice.

[AzureWebAppV1](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureWebAppV1/README.md)

[AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md)

How do you choose which one to use in a new YAML release pipeline?  I just want to make sure I am using the version that is most future-proof - I have 25 release pipelines and don't want to have to re-do them unless necessary.

The way the help is written, hard to compare feature to feature to spot the key "must-haves".  Some Microsoft online examples use both.  Both are still marked as "In Development" in the readme and both are >1 year old since last check in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The simplest way to deploy to an Azure Web App is to use the **Azure Web App Deploy** (AzureWebApp) task.
2. By default, your deployment happens to the root application in the Azure Web App. You can deploy to a specific virtual application by using the `VirtualApplication` property of the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task.
3. **Azure App Service Deploy** task allows users to modify configuration settings in configuration files (*.config files) inside web packages and XML parameters files (parameters.xml), based on the stage name specified.

Comment: Thanks Cece.  I'll go with your recomendation.  Is there a reason there are two different ways?  I appreciate Azure App Service Deploy can do config/xml - just wondered why that capability is not added to Azure Web App Deploy and instead packaged in a different task.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, but I just noticed Web App Deploy takes much less time than Service App Deploy. I was wondering how come a simple zip deploy (Service App Deploy) can take so long. So I looked around and found there's also that Web App Deploy, so I tested it.

My project (React/Next small sized app) normally takes 6-10 min to deploy with Azure **Service App** Deploy (v4). With Azure **Web App** Deploy (v1) it took a little more than a minute. Wow.